# How do you concatenate two integer values using an update statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute an `UPDATE` statement that takes the current code and adds 0000 at the end of it.  In other words, if i have 255, then i would like to see 255000.  I run this SQL but it does not give me any results.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET code = code + 0000
WHERE curr_qtr = 'q1_2014'
```

Comment: You need to understand the distinction between strings and numbers.

Comment: And... you don't need to type in caps-lock !!

Comment: Do you want 255000 or 2550000 to be the output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it's not a numerical data type you will need to cast the value first.

```
update myTable
set code = cast(code as int) * 10000
where curr_qtr = 'q1_2014'
```

Comment: Wrong.  This still just adds 0 to an integer, doing nothing.

Answer (score 8):

You're not seeing any results because you are adding 0 to a number which is always the same as the number.  Instead, try multiplying by 10000, like this:

```
update myTable
set code = code * 10000
where curr_qtr = 'q1_2014'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not seeing results because you're adding 0 to the value in column code.

There are a couple of things you could do. The easiest way would be to multiply code by 10000.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET code = code * 10000
where curr_qtr = 'q1_2014'
```

if you really want to concatenate (if the string is not always '0000'), then you need to convert the column to a string, concatenate, then convert back to your numeric type:

```
update myTable
set code = convert(int, convert(varchar(20),code) + '0000')
where curr_qtr = 'q1_2014'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding zeroes (255 + 0 = 255) try multiplying by 1000 (255 * 1000 = 255000).
Integers cannot be concatenated, strings do.